# C read and write from named pipe

Tags: c, named-pipes

I ultimately want a solution to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155872/cant-use-named-pipe-from-c-to-communicate-with-shell-script?noredirect=1#comment30044447_20155872) but in true one-step-forward-two-steps-back fashion which is programming, I have been reduced to figuring out why I can't even write a character to a named pipe then get that very same character back. Here is a simple MWE script I have, and the accompanying output I am, regretfully, getting:

**MWE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define PIPE_PATH "testpipe"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   int fd;
   FILE *fp;
   char c;
   int result;
   int contingency;

   //Initialize it for debugging purposes
   c = 0;
   contingency = 0;

   if ( atoi ( argv [ 1 ] ) == 1 )
   {
      printf ("Writer [%s]\n", argv[1]);

      mkfifo ( PIPE_PATH, 0666 );

      fd = open ( PIPE_PATH, O_WRONLY );
      c = getchar();
      printf ( "[%d] [%s]\n", c, &c );

      if ( ( result = write ( fd, &c, 1 ) ) == -1)
      {
         fprintf ( stderr, "error writing to pipe\n" );
         return -1;
      }

      close(fd);
   }
   else if ( atoi ( argv [ 1 ] ) == 2 )
   {
      printf ( "Reader [%s]\n", argv[1] );

      fp = fopen( PIPE_PATH, "r" );
      while ( contingency < 3 && ( c = getc ( fp ) ) != EOF )
      { //contingency set to 3 to avoid infinite loop
         c = getc ( fp );
         putchar ( c );
         printf ( "[%d]\n", c ); //don't print c as a string or the shell will go nuts

         printf ( "\n" );
         contingency++;
      }
      fclose ( fp );

      unlink( PIPE_PATH );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Writer [1]
q
[113] [q]
....
Reader [2]
�[255]
�[255]
�[255]
```

For some reason I am getting a question symbol stuck in hexagon, but which in vim looks like a  y (gamma?) with an umlat over it. Since the ASCII code associated with this character is 255, I am assuming that the pipe is not working as expected and returning the highest value possible. Could somebody please tell me what is going on as I have literally spent the last 6 hours of my life accomplishing nothing?

Comment: I'm not trying to stamp out all traces of fun here, but Airplane! pictures don't really belong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### First error

A big problem here...

```
char c = getc(fp);
```

See that?  That's a big problem.  Why?  Let's look at the definition of `getc()`...

```
int getc(FILE *stream);
```

Yes, it returns `int` not `char`, and that is **Important** with a capital **I** and a bold font.  The `getc()` function (or macro) signals EOF with the `EOF`, which is usually -1, and therefore becomes `0xff` when stored in a `char`.

Always use `int` with `getc()`.

```
int c = getc(fp);
if (c == EOF) {
    ...
}
```

### Second error

Well, why are we getting EOF?  Because `getc()` is called *twice* instead of once...

```
while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    c = getc(fp); // <-- should not be there
    ...
}
```

### Third error

This code is also wrong:

```
char c = ...;
printf("[%d] [%s]\n", c, &c);
```

Yes, `&c` has type `char *` but that does not mean you can print it out with `%s`.  The `%s` specifier is strictly for NUL-terminated strings.  Either use `%c`, or continue using `%s` and NUL-terminate the string you pass it.

```
char c = ...;
printf("[%d] [%c]\n", c, c);
```

Or...

```
char c = ...;
printf("[%d] [%s]\n", c, (char[]){c, '\0'});
```

Comment: But -1 is also valid for `char`, isn't it? I mean, c=0xFF is the same as c=-1 because it is a signed variable, not an unsigned one.

Comment: Yes, but how likely is it that the actual character is `0xff`, and not `EOF`?

Comment: @Claudix: But please note that `char` is not always signed.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't notice you already noticed getc() was called twice. Removing my answer... :P

Comment: No need.  You were probably already writing it by the time I clicked "save".