# Complex getchar() operation in omxplayer

Tags: c++, linux, media-player, getchar

Recently I have been trying to redirect the output of a named pipe into a running instance of omxplayer (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155872/cant-use-named-pipe-from-c-to-communicate-with-shell-script?noredirect=1#comment30044447_20155872) for a minimum working example that doesn't control omxplayer even though it should). I suspected that it had something to do with reading and writing to pipes --perhaps a new line got appended-- so I got some help and wrote a C program which writes to a pipe and reads from it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160119/c-read-and-write-from-named-pipe)) but turns out that it is not a read/write error either. So I went and traced omxplayer's code thinking that no matter how complicated it was, eventually there has to be a place which has standard C++ code which reads user input, and thank god I found it. Here is the method which, to the best of my understanding, is responsible for getting user input and preparing it for the Dbus to do all its heavenly goodness:

```
void Keyboard::Process() 
{
  while(!m_bStop && conn && dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch(conn, 0)) 
  {
    int ch[8];
    int chnum = 0;

    while ((ch[chnum] = getchar()) != EOF) chnum++;

    if (chnum > 1) ch[0] = ch[chnum - 1] | (ch[chnum - 2] << 8);

    if (m_keymap[ch[0]] != 0)
          send_action(m_keymap[ch[0]]);
    else
      Sleep(20);
  }
}
```

As far as I can glean, the `while(!m_bStop...` is a conditional just to make sure things are still working, `m_keymap` is a cypher which matches integers such as `'p'` or `'q'` to enum values such as `ACTION_PAUSE` and `ACTION_QUIT`, and I presume `send_action()` just gets the ball rolling.

**Questions:**

Here is what I do not understand:

1. How is EOF detected when I am not even pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> --> `while ((ch[chnum] = getchar()) != EOF)` (in case you are confused by this, when a movie is playing I press <kbd>p</kbd> to pause the film, not <kbd>p</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>). I have attached a small script below labeled `getchar.c` which illustrates how it is looping forever.
2. Why are we looping for potentially more than 8 iterations in the while loop `while ((ch[chnum] = getchar()) != EOF) chnum++` when the array `ch` is only of length 8?
3. This might be implementation specific, but why an array of size 8 when all inputs are guaranteed to be 1 character long (I can both see it here in the map, and by the fact that keys are processed instantly). Is this in any way related to the arrow keys and the escape key?
4. Assuming it is possible to have more than 1 character, somehow, what is this line supposed to do `if (chnum > 1) ch[0] = ch[chnum - 1] | (ch[chnum - 2] << 8)`?
5. Knowing, finally, how omxplayer reads user generated input, can anyone tell me why my simple script, labelled `omxplayer_test.c`, does not succeed in controlling the player?

**getchar.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   int ch [ 8 ];
   int chnum = 0;


   while ( ( ch [ chnum ] = getchar() ) != EOF ) chnum++;
   printf ( "You will never make it here!\n" );

   return 0;
}
```

**omxplayer_test.c:**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define PIPE_PATH "testpipe"
#define VIDEO_PATH "Matrix.mkv"
#define P_MESSAGE "p"
#define Q_MESSAGE "q"
#define I_MESSAGE "."
#define VIDEO_PLAYER "omxplayer"
#define SLEEP_PERIOD 2L

int main()
{
   int fd;
   pid_t pid;
   pid_t wpid;
   int status;
   char shellCmd [ 1000 ];
   struct timespec time1, time2; //used for sleeping
   bool parent;
   char c;

   parent = false;

   //Make pipe BEFORE forking
   mkfifo ( PIPE_PATH, 0666 );

   if ( ( pid = fork () ) < 0 )
   {
      perror ( "Fork Failed\n" );
      return -1;
   }
   else if ( pid == 0 )
   { //first child launches the movie
      sprintf ( shellCmd,  "%s %s < %s >/dev/null 2>&1", VIDEO_PLAYER,  VIDEO_PATH, PIPE_PATH );
      if ( system ( shellCmd ) == -1 )
      {
         printf ( "Error: %s\n", shellCmd );
         fflush(stdout);
      }
      printf ("First child finished\n");
      fflush (stdout);
   }
   else
   {
      if ( ( pid = fork () ) < 0 )
      {
         perror ( "Fork Failed\n" );
         return -1;
      }
      else if ( pid == 0 )
      { //second child waits x seconds then pauses/unpauses/quits movie
         time1.tv_sec = SLEEP_PERIOD; //sleep for x seconds
         time1.tv_nsec = 0L; //Dont worry about milli seconds

         nanosleep ( &time1, &time2 );

         //Suprisingly, this signal which gets ball rolling works
         fd = open ( PIPE_PATH, O_WRONLY );
         write ( fd, I_MESSAGE, sizeof ( I_MESSAGE ) );

         nanosleep ( &time1, &time2 );

         printf ( "Sleep over, pausing movie\n");
         fflush(stdout);

         write ( fd, I_MESSAGE, sizeof ( P_MESSAGE ) );

         nanosleep ( &time1, &time2 );

         printf ( "Sleep over, unpausing movie\n");
         fflush(stdout);

         write ( fd, P_MESSAGE, sizeof ( P_MESSAGE ) );

         nanosleep ( &time1, &time2 );

         printf ( "Sleep over, quiting movie\n");
         fflush(stdout);

         write ( fd, Q_MESSAGE, sizeof ( Q_MESSAGE ) );
         close ( fd );

         printf ("Second child finished\n");
         fflush (stdout);
      }
      else
      {
         parent = true;
      }
   }

   while ( ( wpid = wait ( &status ) ) > 0 )
   {
      printf ( "Exit status of %d was %d (%s)\n", ( int ) wpid, status, ( status == 0 ) ? "accept" : "reject" );
      fflush(stdout);
   }

   if ( parent == true )
   {
      printf ("deleting pipe\n");
      fflush(stdout);
      unlink ( PIPE_PATH );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@puk I stumbled upon your 'old´ question but in case you didn't have it answered by yourself.

Look at something similar on https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/issues/131. As `omxplayer` releases 0.3.x comes from this '`popcornmix`' repository, I will answer these questions there because it *is* a better place for your `omxplayer` questions ;)

But I will answer the question why your `omxplayer_test.c` isn't working *here*, as it is *your code* that let `omxplayer` fail :) *Strictly not true, as it is a current issue in `omxplayer` :(*

The sending of I_MESSAGE surprises me the most, as I don't know of any keyboard input handling on a '.' character. On the other hand, 'i' commands omxplayer to go to the previous chapter. So if you didn't key-mapped anything on the '.' input key or meant the real 'i' actions, just leave that out; it isn't (and shouldn't be) needed to start `omxplayer`.

To pause `omxplayer`, your typo'd it with the `I_MESSAGE` in stead of `P_MESSAGE`.

But sending commands to omxplayer with the write() and the **sizeof()** of the message causes the same effect as mentioned in forementioned issue. The `sizeof()` of an `x_MESSAGE` gives 2 as result back, and not 1 (one)! The `sizeof()` counts in the `'\0'-character` of a (c-coded) string; e.g. `"p"` is stored as `'p''\0'`, so at least 2 characters. So use **`strlen()`** (which needs `#include <string.h>`) in stead, as it will sent only the `x_MESSAGE` character.