# Arbitrary sleeping in threading's wait with timeout

Tags: python, python-2.7, sleep, python-multithreading

Before I start describing my question, it might worth mentioning that I'm using Python 2.7. I haven't checked, but this might be irrelevant for Python 3.x.

While working with Python's [Queues](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue), I've discovered something strange. Usually, when *getting* an object from the Queue, I allow long but finite timeout (such as a few seconds), to allow debugging and error reporting in case no object was found, when one was expected. What I've found out is that sometimes there's a strange gap between the time when an object was inserted into a previously empty Queue, and the time the `get` method of the very same Queue has returned that object, even though the method was called before the `put` was called for that object.

Digging a little bit I've discovered that the gap was filled by sleeping. In the `Queue` module, if the `timeout` argument that is being passed to the `get` method is not `None`, and is positive, the `non_empty` [`Condition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects)'s `wait` method is called with a positive argument (that is not 100% precise; in fact, the `Queue`'s "`_qsize`" method, which returns the length of the underlying `deque` is first verified to return 0, but as long as the queue was empty in the first place, the next thing is the condition's wait).

The `Conditions`'s `wait` method acts differently if it gets a timeout or not. If it does not get any timeout, it simply calls `waiter.acquire`. This is defined in `C` and is beyond what I understand, but it seems like it works properly. However, if timeout **is** given, a bizarre sequence of sleeps occur instead, when the sleep times start at some arbitrary size (1 milisecond), and gets longer over time. Here's the exact code which runs:

```
# Balancing act:  We can't afford a pure busy loop, so we
# have to sleep; but if we sleep the whole timeout time,
# we'll be unresponsive.  The scheme here sleeps very
# little at first, longer as time goes on, but never longer
# than 20 times per second (or the timeout time remaining).
endtime = _time() + timeout
delay = 0.0005 # 500 us -> initial delay of 1 ms
while True:
    gotit = waiter.acquire(0)
    if gotit:
        break
    remaining = endtime - _time()
    if remaining <= 0:
        break
    delay = min(delay * 2, remaining, .05)
    _sleep(delay)
```

This is clearly the reason for the gap I've found between the time the new object was put into the previously-empty Queue, and the time that the already-called get method has returned that object. As the delay time grows exponentially until blocked by a huge (from my perspective) size of 0.05 seconds, it creates surprising and unwanted significant sleeps in my application's life.

Can you explain what's the purpose of this? Are Python developers assume no Python user will care about such time lengths? Is there a quick workaround or a proper fix? Do you recommend me to overload the threading module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently got hit by the same problem, and I also tracked it down to this exact block of code in the `threading` module.

It sucks.

---

> Can you explain what's the purpose of this? Are Python developers assume no Python user will care about such time lengths?

Beats me...

---

> Do you recommend me to overload the threading module?

Either overload the threading module, or migrate to `python3`, where this part of the implementation has been fixed.

In my case, migrating to python3 would have been a huge effort, so I chose the former.  What I did was:

1. I created a quick `.so` file (using `cython`) with an interface to `pthread`.  It includes python functions which invoke the corresponding `pthread_mutex_*` functions, and links against `libpthread`.  Specifically, the function most relevant to the task we're interested in is [pthread_mutex_timedlock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html).
2. I created a new `threading2` module, (and replaced all `import threading` lines in my codebase with `import threading2`).  In `threading2`, I re-defined all the relevant classes from `threading` (`Lock`, `Condition`, `Event`), and also ones from `Queue` which I use a lot (`Queue` and `PriorityQueue`).  The `Lock` class was completely re-implemented using `pthread_mutex_*` functions, but the rest were much easier -- I simply subclassed the original (e.g. `threading.Event`), and overridden `__init__` to create my new `Lock` type. The rest just worked.

The implementation of the new `Lock` type was very similar to the original implementation in `threading`, but I based the new implemenation of `acquire` on the code I found in `python3`'s `threading` module (which, naturally, is much simpler than the abovementioned "balancing act" block). This part was fairly easy.

(Btw, the result in my case was 30% speedup of my massively-multithreaded process.  Even more than I expected.)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to be sure that Queue is not doing something weird is to use the method get_nowait and the Exception Empty. Take a look at these lines that I have in our production servers. (Of course modified to fit in this example).

```
from Queue import Queue, Empty

while receiver.isAlive:
    try:
        rec = Record(queue.get_nowait())
    except Empty:
        # Set someTime with the value you want
        someTime = 0.1
        sleep(someTime)
    else:
        doSomething(rec)
```

Also, have in mind the following:

> > The time.sleep() function uses the underlying operating system’s sleep() function. Ultimately there are limitations of this function. For example on a standard Windows installation, the smallest interval you may sleep is 10 – 13 milliseconds. The Linux kernels tend to have a higher tick rate, where the intervals are generally closer to 1 millisecond.

Comment: Your note about `time.sleep` is interesting, but in any case I was trying to avoid sleeping. Hence the way you've presented of avoiding using `Queue's` timeout is also irrelevant. I was looking for a way of getting the expected behaviour, and your alternative has the exact same problem - it creates gaps (of some resolution), which are not created when not passing timeout at all.

Comment: @Bach: you do understand that your script is not executed on a real-time system: there *always* be unexpected delays: OS may schedule your process to run whenever it likes. You could try to [switch from the sleep to a busy loop for small timeouts](https://gist.github.com/zed/7770492) ([context](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20175873/4279))