# threading.Event().wait() is not notified after calling event.set()

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I came across a very strange issue when using threading.Event() and couldn't understand what is going on? I must have missed something, please can you point it out?

I have a Listener class which shares the same event object with signal handler, here is my simplified code:

```
import threading, time

class Listener(object):    

    def __init__(self, event):        
        super(Listener, self).__init__()
        self.event = event

    def start(self):                
        while not self.event.is_set():            
            print("Listener started, waiting for messages ...")    
            self.event.wait()

        print("Listener is terminated ...")
        self.event.clear()    

event = threading.Event()

def handler(signum, frame):    
    global event
    event.set()
    print('Signal handler called with signal [%s]' % signum)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    listener = Listener(event)
    listener.start()
```

After I run the code, I press ctrl+c to interrupt it, nothing actually happens. I have to use kill -9 to kill the process if I want to quit. However if I supply an argument to `event.wait()`, it worked. but it keeps printing out:

> Listener started, waiting for messages ..."

every timedout seconds. But it will print out:

> Listener is terminated ...

upon Ctrl+c which is what I want.

```
while not self.event.is_set():
        print("Listener started, waiting for messages ...")
        self.event.wait(1)
```

Why do I have to give a timeout argument in `event.wait()` to make it responding to ctrl+c event please? According to the document http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects, the event.wait() Threads that call `wait()` once the flag is true will not block at all. I am using python 2.7.3 by the way.

Comment: Probably this link might help you - http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/802572-waiting-event-blocks-all-signals. Basically, it explains that signals are treated by interpreter, while `event.wait()` by C function. So interpreter simply waits for C function to exit, which doesn't happen, unless you specify a timeout.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Ilia. It helped.

Answer (score 2):

There are several threads discussing related problems with python's threads, interrupts, locks, events.

For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146351/arbitrary-sleeping-in-threadings-wait-with-timeout/22310073) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631441/interruptible-thread-join-in-python), but there are more.

The situation is much better in python3, where the implementation of `wait()` was improved, to make it intterruptible.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you? Basically, start another thread for Listener and wait there while main thread waits for signal.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading, signal

class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        super(Listener, self).__init__()
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        while not self.event.is_set():                                                                                                                                            
            print("Listener started, waiting for messages ...")
            self.event.wait()

        print("Listener is terminated ...")
        self.event.clear()

event = threading.Event()

def handler(signum, frame):
    global event
    event.set()
    print('Signal handler called with signal [%s]' % signum)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    listener = Listener(event)
    listener.start()
    while listener.is_alive():
        pass
```

Comment: Many thanks Rumple, this has definitely worked. But having a separate thread running probably not ideal. I will just use self.event.wait(1) instead. But again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is similar to the original.

Differences:

1. subclass the `Thread` class, use `run` (vs start)
2. use a simple `wait()` with no timeout, which is more predictable
3. signal handler doesn't trigger the `Event` directly. Instead, it just implicitly wakes up the main process, which is sitting on `signal.pause()`.
4. main proc triggers `Event.set()` after it wakes up from `pause()` -- main proc will do this on *any* signal, not just `SIGINT` (control-C).  For testing purposes, there's an alarm call after two seconds.

Hope this helps!

### source

```
import signal, threading, time

class Listener(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, event):        
        super(Listener, self).__init__()
        self.event = event

    def run(self):                
        print("Listener started, waiting for messages ...")    
        while not self.event.wait():
            print('(timeout)')
        print("Listener is terminated ...")
        self.event.clear()    


event = threading.Event()

def handler(signum, _frame):    
    # global event
    # event.set()
    print('Signal handler called with signal [%s]' % signum)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
    signal.alarm(2)

    listener = Listener(event)
    listener.start()

    print '* PAUSE'
    signal.pause()              # wait for a signal

    print '* SIGNALLING'
    event.set()
    listener.join()
    print('* DONE')
```

### output

```
Listener started, waiting for messages ...
* PAUSE
Signal handler called with signal [14]
* SIGNALLING
Listener is terminated ...
* DONE
```